# PostgreSQL - Add days to current_data with condition

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add a day to current_date in between only when from hour is bigger then to hour
can any one help?

see code:

```
AND EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM jsonb_array_elements((${hours})::jsonb) hours(e)
          WHERE hours.e->'active' = 'true'
          AND now() BETWEEN
              current_date + 
                (LEFT(hours.e->>'from', 2))::INTEGER * INTERVAL '1 HOUR' +
                (RIGHT(hours.e->>'from', 2))::INTEGER * INTERVAL '1 MINUTE' AND
              current_date +
                // add day if from is bigger then to
                (LEFT(hours.e->>'to', 2))::INTEGER * INTERVAL '1 HOUR' +
                (RIGHT(hours.e->>'to', 2))::INTEGER * INTERVAL '1 MINUTE' )
```

a

Comment: Please share some sample data, corresponding expected output and a full query

Comment: hours = [{ from: '1200' to: '2200' active: true }, { from: '2300' to: '0600' active: true }].

Comment: I'm want to check if now is between  a set of times in hours array.
and I will like to add a day to current_date if from is bigger then to.